# UserControl Invalidate() method. How to properly invalidate the child controls in a UserControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, invalidation

I have created my UserControl class and everything works as it should. Just wondering what method Invalidate does. It actually does not invalidate controls in my class, and I have not found any effects when it is called. Could anyone explain what this method does in the UserControl classes.

[image]

Comment: It inherits the method from Control.  Which does the plain thing, it forces the Paint event to be generated again.  Doing anything fancy with UserControl.Paint is unusual.

Comment: I was thinking the same but I needed to implement my own one to invalidate the controls in the UserControl. That is the reason I ask. I know that theoretically it is inherited.

Comment: 'Invalidate' is referring to the displayed pixels, not any functionality of the controls. You use it if you coded the Paint/OnPaint event and want it to happen e.g. after changing some parameters, like a brush color or a coordinates of a line you draw etc.. - Note that it will propagate to all nested controls.

Comment: @TaW I do understand it. I just thought that the Invalidate will Invalidate the controls which are part of the UserControl. But their Invalidate methods are not called. I have found the workaround by writing my own method which invalidates the child controls. But I just think if I have not missed something.

Comment: No, it will not call their Invalidate, but it should trigger their Paint/OnPaint events as it will make sure that all necessary pixels get repainted.

Comment: @TaW just checked - It triggers Paint event but it does not trigger child controls Paint events. I just try to understand what is the correct way of Invalidating UserControls.

Comment: It should but not in the sense that they will always be called; if they are not visible there is no nothing to update; e.g. non-selected tabpages and their controls will never repaint/refresh themselves, no matter what you do. Can you explain your 'check' and most of all what you want to accomplish by Invalidating the uc and its controls?

Comment: *_It should but not in the sense that they will always be called; if they are not visible there is no nothing to update_* please the picture I have added to my question. The example control is outlined by the red ellipse. Then I call Invalidate no child control Paint events are called. I have to do it "manually". Is it the correct behaviour or I am missing something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148384/discussion-between-taw-and-peterj).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a `UserControl` `Invalidate` all **nested** controls you need to call a special overload of [`Invalidate(invalidateChildren)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz8ytzt0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
yourUserControl.Invalidate(true);
```

> Invalidates a specific region of the control and causes a paint
>   message to be sent to the control. Optionally, invalidates the child
>   controls assigned to the control.

Note the remarks:

> Remarks
>
> Calling the Invalidate method does not force a synchronous paint; to
>   force a synchronous paint, call the Update method after calling the
>   Invalidate method. When this method is called with no parameters, the
>   entire client area is added to the update region.

**Update**

If you want to call this from a thread other than the UI thread you need to use `Invoke`, maybe like this:

```
public delegate void InvalidateUC();
public InvalidateUC myInvalidateDelegate;

public void InvalidateMethod()
{
    yourUserControl1.Invalidate(true);
}
```

Now, after doing

```
myInvalidateDelegate = new InvalidateUC(InvalidateMethod);
```

You can call this from the other thread

```
yourForm.yourUserControl1.Invoke(myInvalidateDelegate);
```

note that if you are not quite sure whether the call actually  comes from a non-ui thread you can (and should) add the condition

```
if (yourForm.yourUserControl1.InvokeRequired)..
```

Comment: There's a HUGE caveat that isn't (should be) mentioned in the remarks of the docs. Calling `.Invalidate(true)` will _not_ trigger `OnInvalidated` for any of the child controls.